# Why command color disappears when I switch user?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am current logged-in as `agochar` through GUI login. Whenever I typed any command in terminal it is displayed in **blue** color but when I switch user `sudo su anupam` and typed any command in terminal it becomes colorless? I am not expert in this field as I am just starting to learn linux. It is not too serious problem but it would be more easier to learn linux command line if someone could help me solving this issue?

Comment: What is displayed in **blue** color? The command or the command output? Also what shell are you using? `bash`, `zsh` or any other.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, ```zsh``` for user ```agochar``` and ```bash``` for user ```anupam```

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, command is in **blue** color and output of some commands also are colorful...

Comment: Both shells use different configuration shell files to apply those styles. I will provide a possible solution.

Comment: Sure, I will be waiting.

Answer (score 2):

Terminal settings, the appearance of the command prompt, color, etc, are set by the shell startup scripts.  For `bash`, the most commonly used shell, the files are located at `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, and `~/.bashrc`.

When you run `sudo`, you are running commands as another user with different startup scripts, and possibly a different shell.  In particular, the root user and newly created users usually have bare startup scripts.  In comments, you mention using `zsh`, while root and new users are most likely set up to use `bash` by default.

I'm not familiar with configuring `zsh`.  However, the easiest way to quickly set up a colorful prompt in most shells is to use [Starship](https://starship.rs/).  Depending on the distro you use, it may be found in the package repositories.

Comment: Thanks for information, also suggest me how to make changes to make command colorful?

Comment: Edited answer...

Answer (score 2):

For `zsh` shells you might be using `zsh-syntax-highlighting`. In my case to be able to get *blue commands* I have to source the path `/usr/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh`. Not only commands are affected by this configuration, also strings between `" "`  and `' '`, pathnames, non-existing commands are affected by this configutation. For example, I get this behavior by using that `zsh-syntax-highlighting`:

[image]

In `bash` you cannot use the configuration file used in `zsh` so you should install another one. An alternative to `zsh-syntax-highlighting` would be `ble.sh`.
You can use the following commands to install it, but first, make you sure you are logged as `anupam` user (given that this one uses the `bash` shell):

```bash
curl -L https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh/releases/download/nightly/ble-nightly.tar.xz | tar xJf -
mv ble-nightly* ~/.local/share/blesh
echo 'source ~/.local/share/blesh/ble.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Or you can check [its git reposotory](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh) and follow the different installation methods to install it on your operating system.
However, in its git repository I noticed a little bug (unless in my case it did not work at all), because they use:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/blesh
mv ble-nightly* ~/.local/share/blesh
echo 'source ~/.local/share/blesh/ble.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
```

but actually the path `~/.local/share/blesh/ble.sh` does not exist. The actual path would be something like `~/.local/share/blesh/ble-nightly-20221112+0c6291f/ble.sh`. So I suggest you use the commands I provided before. *(Not sure if the command `mv` behaves differently in **macOS**)*

---

Finally when you re-login with `anupam` you should be able to get a similar behavior as `zsh`:

[image]

**Note:** Using those configurations might be a little bit slow when you paste large commands to the terminal. I noticed that in `zsh` is usually slower pasting commands than in `bash`.

Comment: > *However, in its git repository I noticed a little bug* ... Actually, this issue was reported at https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh/pull/240, and now I have changed the directory name in the tarball and updated `README` for the commands to install the nightly version.

Comment: @akinomyoga that's so good, glad to know this has been fixed. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score -1):

**If you're using bash**

Because you have your own configuration file in the `/home/$USER/.bashrc` for that $USER only. If you want that profile to be used as `root` profile, then do this instead:

```
if [[ $UID == 0 ]]; then
   export PS1="root_Profile"
else
   export PS1="user_Profile"
fi
```

`$UID` == 0 means it's in root account, else it's $USER account/profile

Comment: sorry but it did not worked...